# Sorting arrays in opposite order in Rby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, spaceship-operator

I'm new to Ruby and need a piece of code to be explained to me. The array to be sorted is this one:

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", 
"A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]
```

The code block below sorts this array `books` A-Z

```
books.sort! { |firstBook, secondBook| firstBook <=> secondBook }
```

The code block below sorts this array `books` Z-A

```
books.sort! { |firstBook, secondBook| secondBook <=> firstBook }
```

Why is this? Why does the first one sort A-Z and the second one Z-A? I sort of understand the combined comparison operator `<=>`. It returns -1, 1, or 0 depending on the comparison. But how does this sort things? Thank you!

Comment: Note that `<=>` is called the Spaceship Operator and it performs [three way comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort operator does what it looks like: it tells you if something is less than, greater than, or equal to another object in sort order. So your first block asks "Is `firstBook` before or after `secondBook`", and the second block asks "is `secondBook` is before or after `first book`". As you can see, the answer to those are opposite:

- "A" comes *before* "B" (`"A" <=> "B" == -1`)
- "B" comes *after* "A" (`"B" <=> "A" == 1`)

So if you flip the order of the question, you get the opposite answer, and that means the (comparison type) [sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) gives the opposite result.

Comment: So what I'm gathering is, if a letter is later in the alphabet, it has a bigger value. So something like "A" <=> "B" would return -1. Because "B" is bigger, does sort put it at the end? And if you did "B" <=> "A" returning 1, it would put "B" at the beginning? So overall, if it returns 1, the first operand will be put before, and if it returns -1, the first operand will be put after?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. ( I think you have it backwards though, smaller values come before larger values, so `smaller <=> larger == -1`). A comparison sort algorithm always looks at two items at a time and figures out which goes first. Ruby uses the values `-1`, `0`, and `1` to indicate this when it is sorting. In ruby though, you can hijack this behavior and sort however you choose, so what is "smaller" and what is "larger" is up to you. That is why you can pass a block to `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting algorithm uses the return value from the block, in this case it is the result of the comparison operator (`<=>`). When `-1` is return the order of `a` and `b` will remain the same (i.e. `a` comes before `b`Depending on the value the algorithm will either keep the current order of `a` and `b` in theto know whether `a` should be sorted before `b` (`-1`), or after (`1`), or if the two are equivalent (`0`).

The algorithm repeatedly compares adjacent pairs of elements until all elements are in order.

Let's add some output to see what happens when you call sort on your list of books. This will give us some insight to what the sort method is doing. I've added comments to illustrate how each step of the sorting has changed the books array. Please note that talking about how sort "swaps" positions is simplified in this example.

```
> books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]
> books.sort! do |a, b|
>   result = a <=> b
>   puts %(\n"#{ a }" <=> "#{ b }"  #=> #{ result })  # Print out which elements are being compared and the result
>   result
> end

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "War and Peace"  #=> -1
# ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** No change

"War and Peace" <=> "Utopia"  #=> 1
# ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** Positions of "Utopia" and "War and Peace" are swapped

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "Utopia"  #=> -1
# ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** No change

"War and Peace" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1
# ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "War and Peace", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** Positions of "War and Peace" and "A Brief History of Time" are swapped

"Utopia" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1
# ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "A Brief History of Time", "Utopia", "War and Peace", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** Positions of "Utopia" and "A Brief History of Time" are swapped

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1
# ["A Brief History of Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace", "A Wrinkle in Time"]  *** Positions of "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" and "A Brief History of Time" are swapped

"War and Peace" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1
# ["A Brief History of Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "A Wrinkle in Time", "War and Peace"]  *** Positions of "War and Peace" and "A Wrinkle in Time" are swapped

"Utopia" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1
# ["A Brief History of Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "A Wrinkle in Time", "Utopia", "War and Peace"]  *** Positions of "Utopia" and "A Wrinkle in Time" are swapped

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1
# ["A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace"]  *** Positions of "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" and "A Wrinkle in Time" are swapped

"A Brief History of Time" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> -1
# ["A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace"]  *** No change

# Done! All elements have been sorted, so the algorithm exits.

=> ["A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "Utopia", "War and Peace"]
```

When the comparison is changed from `a <=> b` to `b <=> a` the results are inverted which causes sorting to be done in the opposite order.

```
> books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]
> books.sort! do |a, b|
>   result = b <=> a
>   puts %(\n"#{ b }" <=> "#{ a }"  #=> #{ result })  # Print out which elements are being compared and the result
>   result
> end

"A Wrinkle in Time" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1

"Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1

"Utopia" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1

"Utopia" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1

"Utopia" <=> "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory"  #=> 1

"War and Peace" <=> "A Brief History of Time"  #=> 1

"War and Peace" <=> "A Wrinkle in Time"  #=> 1

"War and Peace" <=> "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory"  #=> 1

"War and Peace" <=> "Utopia"  #=> 1
=> ["War and Peace", "Utopia", "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "A Wrinkle in Time", "A Brief History of Time"]
```

See also the documentation for [Array#sort!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort-21)